# Python/FLASK - html form return strings. How check if it containt number?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, isnumeric

I have very simple code - Im looking for better solution my case:
I have:
 - 2 input text + submit button

Input forms always returns text as string.
Do you know better solution (and shorter) to **pass only numeric values** (and for non numeric - show "error") except gather all letters in list and check statement *if text from input is not in list with letters*?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/licz/", methods=['GET'])
def search():
    licz1 = request.args.get('liczba1')
    licz2 = request.args.get('liczba2')
    notnumbers = ['q','w','e','r','t','y']
    if licz1 and licz2 != None:

        if licz1 not in notnumbers:
            sumaliczenia = int(licz1) + int(licz2)
            return render_template('liczenie.html', suma=sumaliczenia)
        else:
            sumaliczenia = "error"
            return render_template('liczenie.html', suma=sumaliczenia)

    else:
        return render_template('liczenie.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Template code (from comment below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Formularz</title>
    </head>
    <body> Result is {{ suma }}
      <form action="/licz/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="liczba1">
        <input type="text" name="liczba2"> <button type="submit">Send</button> 
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: No, its not duplicate, because input text always returns string not int.

Comment: As far as I see, you have different options: (1) via HTML using `type="number"` like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number (you can hide the arrow inside the input element using CSS), (2) convert data to int using a try/except inside python, (3) detect int inside string using a regex, (4) compare list representation of string to a list of all numbers `0...9`

Comment: Please provide template code.

Comment: Template code: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formularz</title>
</head>
<body>

        Result is {{ suma }}

    <form action="/licz/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="liczba1">
 <input type="text" name="liczba2">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You could just try to cast your inputs to int. If there is no numeric value in it Python will raise a ValueError, which you can catch and do the error stuff.

```
try:
    input1 = int(input1)
    input2 = int(input2)
except ValueError as e:
    # print error
else:
    # valid
    sum = input1 + input2
```